# Sending JSON + File via Postman

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, multipartform-data

I have an Android app that posts the following multi-part content to my application. The request contains JSON as well as an image File.

```
        AndroidNetworking.upload(baseUrl+"updateuserprofile")
            .addMultipartFile("UserImage",userImage)
            .setTag("UserImage")
            .addMultipartParameter("PhoneNumber",phone)
            .addMultipartParameter("UserId",userId)
            .addMultipartParameter("firstName",firstName)
            .addMultipartParameter("LastName",lastName)
            .setPriority(Priority.HIGH)
            .setOkHttpClient(okHttpClient)
            .build();
```

My app is an ASP .NET WebAPI 2.0 app and I cannot figure out how to `EditProfile` parameter that always turns out to be `NULL`.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> EditProfile ([FromBody] EditProfile profile)
{
    // `profile` is populated if only JSON is sent.
    // `profile` is `NULL` if multi-part content is sent.
}

public class EditProfile
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string MobileNo { get; set; }
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public string ImageString { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase PostedFile { get; set; }
}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

AS you are sending a multi-part content, it is not a json but a form data. So instead of using `[FromBody]` you should use `[FromFrom]`. (`[FromForm]` is a feature from ASP.Net Core, as you are using Full Framework, it wont work for you)

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> EditProfile ([FromForm] EditProfile profile)
{
    // `profile` will not be populated if JSON is sent.
    // `profile` will be populated if multi-part content is sent.
}

public class EditProfile
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string MobileNo { get; set; }
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public string ImageString { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase PostedFile { get; set; }
}
```

I believe that ASP.Net Web API (Full framework) does not allow you to add a HttpPostedFile as part of your model. If you find any problem like `PostedFile` been `null`. Remove the HttpPostedFile as a parameter of your action.

And if you need to accept a Json request without the file and a multi-part form data with a file. You should remove `[FromForm]` from your parameter, and let the framework to handle that for you.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> EditProfile (EditProfile profile, HttpPostedFileBase postedFile)
{
    // `profile` should be populated with a JSON or multi-part content
    // `postedFile` will be  populated only if multi-part content is sent with a file.
}

public class EditProfile
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string MobileNo { get; set; }
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public string ImageString { get; set; }
    // REMOVE HttpPostedFileBase property
}
```

Comment: I tried both approaches. `[FromForm]` requires a dependency on `AspNetCore` which is not possible for me. The next example with `HttpPostedFileBase ` throws an `InvalidOperationException`: `Can't bind multiple parameters ('editProfile' and 'postedFile') to the request's content`.

Comment: Sorry. The first one using `[FromForm]` work on asp.net core only. I'll update the answer to make it clear.

Comment: On the second example, did you remove the HttpPostedFileBase from your model?

Comment: Tried it with and without `HttpPostedFileBase` as part of the model. The error is now: `Can't bind multiple parameters ('editProfile' and 'postedFile') to the request's content.`.